# delay qTip call using setTimeout and clearTimeout 

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, settimeout, qtip

This was working fine:

```
$('#panel_derecho a.tooltip').each(function(){

  $(this).qtip({
     content: { url: '/includes/qtip.php?'+$(this).attr('rel')+' #'+$(this).attr('div'), text:'<center><img  src="/images/loader.gif" alt="loading..." /></center>'  },
     show: { delay: 700, solo: true,effect: { length: 500 }},
     hide: { fixed: true, delay: 200 },
     position: {
     corner: {
        target: 'topLeft',
        tooltip: 'middleRight'
                }
                },
     style: {
       name: 'light',
       width: 700,
       padding: 0,border: {
         width: 4,
         radius: 3,
         color: '#5588CC'
      }
       }
   });

});
```

but sometimes the user hovered while scrolling down the page and many calls to qtip that won't be shown where called so thought that adding a timeout was best go (isn't it?)

so i tried to set delayTip var with time to wait (while hover) and to clear it when mouse out:

```
$('#panel_derecho a.tooltip').each(function(){
    var delayTip;

       $(this).bind('mouseover',function(){
            delayTip = setTimeout(function () {
              $(this).qtip({
                 content: { url: '/includes/qtip.php?'+$(this).attr('rel')+' #'+$(this).attr('div'), text:'<center><img  src="/images/loader.gif" alt="loading..." /></center>'  },
                 show: { delay: 700, solo: true,effect: { length: 500 }},
                 hide: { fixed: true, delay: 200 },
                 position: {
                 corner: {
                    target: 'topLeft',
                    tooltip: 'middleRight'
                            }
                            },
                 style: {
                   name: 'light',
                   width: 700,
                   padding: 0,border: {
                     width: 4,
                     radius: 3,
                     color: '#5588CC'
                  }
                   }
               });
           }, 500);
       };
       $(this).bind('mouseout',function(){  clearTimeout(delayTip);  });

    });
```

the ting is that the tooltip is not shown and no errors are jumping in firebug,

what am I missing?

Comment: I'd add some debug code in there just to make sure you know the mouseover and mouseout event handlers are firing. `console.log('mouseover fired')`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When the timeout fires the `this` keyword refers to the global object (most likely the `window`), try to do something like this:

```
$('#panel_derecho a.tooltip').each(function(){
    var delayTip = 0;
    var self = $(this);
    self.bind('mouseover',function(){
        if (delayTip === 0) delayTip = setTimeout(function () {
            self.qtip({
                content: { url: '/includes/qtip.php?'+self.attr('rel')+' #'+self.attr('div'), text:'<center><img  src="/images/loader.gif" alt="loading..." /></center>'  },
                show: { delay: 700, solo: true,effect: { length: 500 }},
                hide: { fixed: true, delay: 200 },
                position: {
                    corner: {
                        target: 'topLeft',
                        tooltip: 'middleRight'
                    }
                },
                style: {
                    name: 'light',
                    width: 700,
                    padding: 0,border: {
                        width: 4,
                        radius: 3,
                        color: '#5588CC'
                    }
                }
            });
            delayTip = 0;
        }, 500);
    };
    self.bind('mouseout',function(){ clearTimeout(delayTip); delayTip = 0; });
});
```

Comment: This ways looks like an improvement. The tip is shown but it's called many times when hover... ?

Comment: Hey, thanks!, like this goes better; but first time hover (i check using console.log) the qtip is not fired, second+ times yes. (and  only one call); why is this posible? also i moved delayTip out of the .each() function